# Using Laravel Package Classes Into Another

Tags: laravel, package, service-provider

I created a simple Laravel package that I have already deployed to GitHub and Packagist successfully. It can be installed via Composer as expected.

Now...

I am creating a second package that would use the first one's functionality, but it is not showing.

In the current package, I do:  `use Me\Package\Models\Extra,` in the controller of my second package and, I get the class is not found.

I tried using the ServiceProvider `register()` function, but it doesn't work.

Comment: You should include the first package in the second package's `composer.json` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Composer to install your first package into the second package:

Lets call the first package `codiiv/first-package`.

Go the project root of your second package and type this command to your terminal:
`composer require codiiv/first-package`.

Comment: That part is done and successful. I turns out it was a typo in my class declaration #smh